# Trying to install Burg Bootloader. /boot/burg/burg.cfg missing

Tags: burg

I am using the grub customizer GUI but I can't get it to work.

I get this error message:

```
burg-mkconfig couldn't be executed successfully. error message:
Generating burg.cfg ...
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: cannot stat `/boot/burg/locale'.
No path or device is specified.
```

I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I noticed that this question was asked a long time ago, and an answer was provided. If the answer that was given fixed your problem, please mark it as the answer. See http://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 5):

Copy your `locale` folder from `/boot/grub/` into `/boot/burg/`.
That did the trick for me!